# How to protect an express node.js web app by requiring a hardcoded username+password combination?

Tags: http, express, https, passport.js, password-protection

I want to do this without using any third party library like [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/).

All the traffic is going through https, so I assume it is safe, even if the username+password are transmitted clear text.

Is there some build it mechanism in HTTP protocol for such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, to both questions, it's *not* safe at all and HTTP(s) itself does not deal with login logic.

So whatever system you want to put in place you either use an existing middleware/lib or you implement it yourself (very bad idea).